# Sencha Build is failing after After Mac upgrade to Monterey version 12.1

Tags: extjs

I'm working on a classic Sencha project using a M1-pro Macbook Pro. ... Sencha "$@". java(3259,0x30a9d7000) malloc: Heap corruption detected, free list is damaged at 0x600003dcba80
*** Incorrect guard value: 105553168608752

Answer (score 1):

I've have similar issues ever since migrating to the M1 platform. Sencha CMD's included JRE is not compiled for the ARM architecture and even with Rosetta 2, there still seems to be issues with how the included JRE operates in the different architecture. The best workaround I've found is to switch to a JRE compiled for the ARM architecture and that is also compatible with Sencha CMD. Oracle offers an M1 compatible Java SDK but it is the latest version (17) and it won't work with Sencha CMD which needs a JDK in the version 8-11 range. I've found that Bellsoft's M1 versions seem to work the best. You can download it [here](https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads/)

Answer (score -1):

I've also had similar experiences, but occasionally Sencha CMD will start.

But I have a possible other solution, or an extra step necessary to have the solution from @aatb to work: for me the `db_file` Sencha uses to store the Java environment contained references to older versions of CMD or java.

For me a solution was to remove the file: `~/.install4j`